# Angularjs update scope inside iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

In the following code i'm trying to get subquestions list for each question and show them in the view ,but i have problem in updating subquestion for each question,it don't update so I get same subquestion list for all question.

How can I show each question and list all subquestion under it?

```
  function loadAllQuestionGroup () {
    Questiongroup.query({}).$promise.then(function(group){
        vm.questiongroups = group;
        for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
           var grouptitle=group[i].title
            Question.questionsByQuestionGroup({id:group[i].id}).$promise.then(function(question){
                vm.question = question; 
               for(var j=0;j<question.length;j++){    
                  Subquestion.subquestionsByQuestion({id:question[j].id}).$promise.then(function(subquestion){
                      vm.subquestions=subquestion;
                    });                        
              }
         });
        }
      });
    }

 <div ng-repeat="question in vm.question">
   {{question.name}}
   <div ng-repeat="subquestion in vm.subquestions">
     {{subquestion.name}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please try with $scope.$apply() after updating subquestions.

Comment: I have tried but i get null data

Comment: get $digest already in progress

Comment: can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not an issue related with angular scope, it's pure javascript scope that you have trouble with. If you making asynchronous calls in the loop, you will receive each time the last element. To fix it, you should wrap promises inside loop with anonymous functions.

Check this classic example(you can think that setTimeout function is equivalent of your `Question.questionsByQuestionGroup({id:group[i].id}).$promise`, they are both async functions)

```js
//THIS IS EQUIVALENT TO YOUR CASE
//In this case it will return each time last element, 5 in this case
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  });
}
//Result: 5 5 5 5 5

//THIS IS HOW YOU SHOULD REFACTOR
//Make a wrapper for async, and it will work as needed
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(index)
    });
  })(j);
}
//Result: 0 1 2 3 4
```

P.S. After you will fix it with wrappers, your code will be even more unreadable, better to refactor it to separate functions.

Comment: I did and index print 0,1,2,3 but scope still don't update

Comment: @Ali-Alrabi also one thing I noticed, you are assigning subquestion to array:
`vm.subquestions=subquestion;`
if you want to have array of different items, you should push it not assign

Answer (score 1):

Individual questions need to be **pushed** to a question list. Create a subquestion list for **each** individual question. Individual subquestions need to be **pushed** to their respective lists.

```
function loadAllQuestionGroup () {
    Questiongroup.query({}).$promise.then(function(group){
        vm.questiongroups = group;
        //Initialize question list
        vm.questionList = [];
        for (var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
            var grouptitle=group[i].title;
            Question
              .questionsByQuestionGroup({id:group[i].id})
              .$promise
              .then(function(question){
                //Push question to list
                vm.questionList.push(question); 
                for (var j=0;j<question.length;j++) {
                    //Initialize subquestion list
                    question.subquestionList = [];
                    Subquestion
                        .subquestionsByQuestion({id:question[j].id})
                        .$promise
                        .then(function(subquestion){
                             //Push subquestion to list
                             question.subquestionList.push(subquestion);
                        })
                   ;                        
                };
              })
            ;
        }
    });
}
```

Subquestion interation (`ng-repeat`) should be done on the `question` iterator.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in vm.questionList">
   {{question.name}}
   <div ng-repeat="subquestion in question.subquestionList">
     {{subquestion.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Notice that a `subquestionList` property was added to **each** `question` in the `questionList`.